# A pagina demora para montar um JS que monta uma <div class='marquee'>

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dias caros amigos,

Estou com uma questão aqui no meu código que esta tirando meu sono, se alguém puder ajudar.

A parada a um seguinte...

Na tela do sistema precisa ficar passando uma(s) mensagen(s) (tipo marquee do HTML) em forma de link para quando o usuário clicar ele ser direcionado para a pagina que esta no link.

Essas mensagens são cadastradas por um usuário especifico então eu pego essas mensagens via query e transformo em links (via PHP) e uso um javascript para passar as mensagens na tela e quando tem mais de uma ele passa uma por vez.

O código esta rodando e faz o quero, porém ele demora um pouco para montar o link (rodar o javascript), ele roda a primeira vez é a mensagem sai assim ( [Globo Teste](http://globoesporte.globo.com/) ) ai depois de um tempo monta a link certo que seria assim o  (Globo Teste)

Sé alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Estou usando o Framework Yii2.
BD SQL SErver 2012.

Tenho os seguintes código.

o php que trás a pesquisa do BD já separando as mensagem (que vem por um cadastro)  separando por , e ''. E transforma a mensagem em links para acessar as mensagens direto desse link rodando na pagina.

```
public static function getNoticias() {
    $models = self::find()
            ->select('ds_alerta, nm_link, nm_imagem')
            ->where('st_ativo = 1')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

    $rec = [];
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        $imagem = '';
        $conteudo = '';

        if (empty($model['nm_link'])) {
            $conteudo = $model['ds_alerta'];
        } else {
            $conteudo = '<a href="' . $model['nm_link'] . '">' . $model['ds_alerta'] . '</a>';
        }

        if (!empty($model['nm_imagem'])) {
            $imagem = '<img src="' . $model['nm_imagem'] . '">';
        }

        $rec[] = $imagem . $conteudo;
    }

    return "'" . implode("','", $rec) . "'";
}
```

O código Js para rodar as mensagem uma por vez. (ele roda cada mensagem de acordo com a virgulo que e jerada na pessquisa do php.

var alertaMensagens ;

$(function () {

```
$('.link-menu').click(function () {
    $(this).find("span").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
});

Util.urlCaminho = $('#pathCaminho').val();

$(function () {
    $(".menu-lateral-body").mCustomScrollbar({
        axis: "y",
        theme: "minimal-dark"
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('click', 'a.manual-download', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        Util.ModalAlertExclusaoJson({
            mensagem: "Clique aqui para obter o manual de utilização?",
            url: $(this).attr('href')
        });
    });

    var indice = 0;
    var tamanho = alertaMensagens.length;

    $(".marquee-text").text(alertaMensagens[indice]);

    var marquee = $('div.marquee');
    marquee.each(function () {
        var mar = $(this), indent = mar.width();
        mar.marquee = function () {
            indent--;
            mar.css('text-indent', indent);
            if (indent < -1 * mar.children('div.marquee-text').width()) {
                if ((indice + 1) > tamanho) {
                    indice = 0;
                } else {
                    indice++;
                }
                indent = mar.width();

                $(".marquee-text").html(alertaMensagens[indice]);
            }
        };
        mar.data('interval', setInterval(mar.marquee, 10 / 6000000));
    });
});
```

})

e a minha div marquee recebe

alertaMensagens = []; para monstrar as mensagen na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Se tiver muitas mensagens vai demorar mesmo, por isso em SqlServer existe o `OFFSET FETCH` ou `row_number()`, para limitar mesmo, imagine se os sites não tivessem paginação, iria levar horas baixar a página para exibir/renderizar tudo.

Creio que no Yii o [`limit()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querytrait#limit()-detail) gere a query tanto para Sql Server quanto para Mysql, então seu código deve ficar assim:

```
$models = self::find()
        ->select('ds_alerta, nm_link, nm_imagem')
        ->where('st_ativo = 1')
        ->limit(10)
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

O `->limit(10)` irá limitar para 10 resultados, **isso é apenas um exemplo**, pode trocar o 10 por quantos achar necessário, desde que não seja um valor muito grande.

Você também pode optar por exibir randomicamente para que "sempre" sejam exibidos itens diferentes, como é demonstrado nesta [resposta do **SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748467/1518921) e basta adaptar para o uso de `NEWID()` como é mostrado nesta [*resposta*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/1518921):

```
$models = self::find()
        ->select('ds_alerta, nm_link, nm_imagem')
        ->where('st_ativo = 1')
        ->orderBy(new Expression('NEWID()'))
        ->limit(10)
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Comment: Valeu Mano, vou tentar aqui, mas já te adianto que mesmo sendo apenas uma mensagem ele montra todo o href e depois monta o link.